# Multi-node Zookeeper on Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, docker-swarm

I'm setting up a multi-node Apache Kafka cluster, but it seems my Zookeeper instances are having trouble communicating with each other.

I'm deploying the cluster as a Docker Swarm stack. I'm aware that, according to [Confluent's docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/installation.html), networking through swarm overlay drivers is not supported. So I'm publishing the ports on all interfaces. However, my Zookeeper instances keep throwing this exception:

```
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client, it probably closed the socket: address = /127.0.0.1:{some_random_port}, session = 0x100fc7d362c0002
```

When I try to execute `zookeeper-shell localhost:12181 ls /brokers/ids` against my Zookeeper instances, it seems that some of my Zookeeper instances manage to connect to a Kafka broker or two, but the instances are not aware of the brokers connected to other Zookeeper instances.

Here's my partial setup:

```yaml
    x-zookeeper-envs: &zookeeper-envs
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1: zookeeper-1:12888:13888;12181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_2: zookeeper-2:22888:23888;22181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_3: zookeeper-3:32888:33888;32181
    
    services:
      zookeeper-1:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.1.1
        <<: *network
        ports:
          - 12181:12181
          - 12888:2888
          - 13888:3888
        deploy:
          placement:
            constraints: [node.labels.worker==1]
        environment:
          <<: *zookeeper-envs
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 12181
          ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
    
      zookeeper-2:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.1.1
        <<: *network
        ports:
          - 22181:22181
          - 22888:2888
          - 23888:3888
        deploy:
          placement:
            constraints: [node.labels.worker==2]
        environment:
          <<: *zookeeper-envs
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
          ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
    
      zookeeper-3:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.1.1
        <<: *network
        ports:
          - 32181:32181
          - 32888:2888
          - 33888:3888
        deploy:
          placement:
            constraints: [node.labels.worker==3]
        environment:
          <<: *zookeeper-envs
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
          ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
```

I have also tried setting the Zookeeper environment variables in this format: `ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1: zookeeper-1:12888:13888::1;12181`, but to no avail.

Comment: In general, Confluent recommends k8s rather than Swarm, but are you able to `ping zookeeper-1` from `zookeeper-2`, for example? Also [In the docs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.8.0/zookeeperStarted.html), it shows only two ports used for cluster setup.

Comment: I could ping other zookeeper instances from each one by their service names. I don't know what I was doing wrong, but I managed to get it running using `zookeeper` image instead of `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper`. I'll post my setup in case anyone else faces the same issue.
At any rate, thanks a bunch @OneCricketeer for your reply. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it running using `zookeeper` image instead of `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper`. Here's my setup in case anyone else struggled with setting multi-node Zookeeper/Kafka on Swarm.

```yaml
version: '3.7'

x-zookeeper-envs: &zookeeper-envs
  ZOO_TICK_TIME: 2000
  ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeper-1:12888:13888;12181 server.2=zookeeper-2:22888:23888;22181 server.3=zookeeper-3:32888:33888;32181

x-kafka-envs: &kafka-envs
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:12181,zookeeper-2:22181,zookeeper-3:32181
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
  KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
  KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
  KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
  KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
  KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
  KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka-1:29092,kafka-2:29093,kafka-3:29094
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 3
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper-1
    <<: *network
    ports:
      - 12181:2181
      - 12888:2888
      - 13888:3888
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.worker==1]
    environment:
      <<: *zookeeper-envs
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1

  zookeeper-2:
    image: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper-2
    <<: *network
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
      - 22888:2888
      - 23888:3888
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.worker==2]
    environment:
      <<: *zookeeper-envs
      ZOO_MY_ID: 2

  zookeeper-3:
    image: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper-3
    <<: *network
    ports:
      - 32181:2181
      - 32888:2888
      - 33888:3888
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.worker==3]
    environment:
      <<: *zookeeper-envs
      ZOO_MY_ID: 3

  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.worker==1]
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      <<: *kafka-envs
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka-1:29092

  kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.worker==2]
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
      - 29093:29093
    environment:
      <<: *kafka-envs
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-2:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9093
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka-2:29093

  kafka-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.worker==3]
    ports:
      - 9094:9094
      - 29094:29094
    environment:
      <<: *kafka-envs
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-3:29094,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9094
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka-3:29094
```